# Send Raw Signals Over Sata Data Cable

Tags: sata

### Question

From inside Windows, is there a way send raw signals down a sata data cable?

Does Windows even that kind of access, or is it dependent on the sata controller?

---

### Background

A buddy's computer has an ssd on sata 0, which can be used to boot into Windows.

A known-working hdd is on sata 1, which uses a custom, hardwired sata data cable.  This hdd does not appear in the BIOS (yes, the port is enabled), nor in Windows.

We know that the sata power cable being used with the hdd is good, because the same power cable works for the ssd.

We believe the custom cable (or the way we wired it to the board) is at fault, and would like investigate.  We want to generate activity on that cable, but don't know how to do so if the connected device is not recognized.

---

Questions/Feedback welcome!

Comment: Have a look in the BIOS to see if the port is disabled.

Comment: @mt025 The port is enabled in the BIOS.  I've updated the question to address this.

Comment: Why exactly are you using a custom cable?

Comment: could you simply take it out of the computer and test the cable with an ohm meter?

Comment: @Ramhound (and Blaine) It's a weird embedded x86 dev board thing.  There's no sata port on the board for sata 1, just bare wires that connect to a sata cable.  I've updated the question to indicate that it could be a wiring arrangement problem.

Comment: @Blaine (see above)